# What's special about a "rare" expedition?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Sometimes if I look at the world map I see sparkly expeditions marked as "Rare". While sometimes these have slightly tougher-than-usual monsters, I haven't noticed the rewards being any different. I still get the same type and number of item rewards and usually end up with yet another velocidrome guild quest.

What's different about "rare" expeditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rare Expeditions will generate different Guild Quests, as well as have an increased chance of gathering Battered Weapon/Armor from blue mining nodes.

Comment: I think certain monsters only show up on Rare Expeditions, too (e.g. Gore Magala)?

Comment: Are there some guild quests that are exclusive to rare expeditions or is it just an increased chance to get them?